# Java with String length limit

Tags: java

I am trying to solve a CodeChef problem in Java and found out that I could not create a String with length > one million chars (with my compiler at least). I pasted the first one million decimal digits of Pi in a string (e.g. String PI = "3.1415926535...151") in the Java file and it fails to compile. When I take out the Pi and replace it with a shorter string like "dog", the code compiles. Can anyone confirm if this is indeed a limitation of Java?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have the error message produced from the compiler?

Comment: @RobertH It is not a duplicate of that question. You can programatically create strings larger than the limit on string literals.

Comment: without the exact error message, this can be same as this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/243097/javac-error-code-too-large

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Can anyone confirm if this is indeed a limitation of Java?

Yes.  There is an implementation limit of 65535 on the length of a string literal<sup>1</sup>.  It is not stated in the JLS, but it is implied by the structure of the class file; see [JVM Spec 4.4.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.4.7) and note that the string length field is 'u2' ... which means a 16 bit unsigned integer.

Note that a `String` object can have up to 2^31 - 1 characters.  The 2^16 -1 limit is actually for string-valued *constant expressions*; e.g. string literals or concatenations of literals that are embedded in the source code of a Java program.

---

If you want to a String that represents the first million digits of Pi, then it would be better to read the characters from a file in the filesystem, or a resource on the classpath.

---

<sup>1 - This limit is actually on the number of bytes in the (modified) UTF-8 representation of the String.  If the string consists of characters in the range 0x01 to 0x7f, then each byte represents a single character.  Otherwise, a character can require up to 6 bytes.</sup>

Answer (score -1):

I think this problem is not related to string literals but to method size: http://chrononsystems.com/blog/method-size-limit-in-java. According to that, the size of the method can not exceed 64k.

Comment: It could be method size related, if the string was declared in a method... but there is not indication of that in the question. If it were the case, then OP would have 2 problems.

Comment: @ColinD: according to [this](http://www.mail-archive.com/help-bison@gnu.org/msg01990.html), it's valid for static initializer too