# Max string literal length is greater than 2^16 -1

Tags: string, scala, apache-spark, maxlength

In Scala 2.11 I am using the Play JSON API and when the line executes it throws an error.

```
val bodyParsed = Json.parse(bodyText.replaceAll("\\\\", ""))
```

That is because the length of `bodyText` is greater than 2^16 - 1.

How can I fix the problem?

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18361219/java-with-string-length-limit) post but I'm not sure whether it's the solution in my case.

Comment: Can you also post the error value ?

Comment: i am unable to capture error as it executes on one of the node. i tried with try and catch but it not coming in to catch. basically i put an accumulator in catch and updating the accumulator but it is not updating the accumulator.

Comment: So what is the max value for String in java, I was reading online it's around 2^32-1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry this has nothing to do with the size of the string. I was able to capture my error in to a variable and see. it looks like the string i am getting is not JSON compliant and was throwing an error.